# Render and display an SVG-File with a Grails Controller

Tags: grails, svg, grails-2.0, grails-controller

I want to create a table that contains svg-images. These images are generated after processing the table data.

My controller looks like this:

```
def render(){
    byte[] array =  SvgExporter.export(imgsource)       
    render file: array, fileName: "my.svg", contentType: 'svg'
    }
```

under grails.mime.types in config.groovy, I defined

```
svg: 'image/svg+xml'
```

the table entry on gsp looks like this:

```
<img src="${createLink(controller: 'testview', action: 'render')}">
```

The funny thing now is that it works if I use PNG instead of SVG, the image gets displayed.

When I use the above code with SVG, the image does not get displayed on the page. When I call the controller directly, the correct svg-image gets downloaded.
Any ideas?

Comment: should be `contentType: 'image/svg+xml' with render?  i'd say, that `grails.mine.types` is not used for rendering.

Comment: it worked. please post it as an answer so i can mark it as solved. thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending the wrong mimetype down with the `render`.  instead use:

```
render contentType: 'image/svg+xml', ...
```

The mappings in `grails.mime.types` are not meant for you to shortcut them, but are used internally in grails.

Comment: Getting error ' can not resolve the symbol  SvgExporter' while implementing  the this function in intellij  def render(){
    byte[] array =  SvgExporter.export(imgsource)       
    render file: array, fileName: "my.svg", contentType: 'image/svg+xml'
    }

Comment: @user830982 `SvgExporter` is an undisclosed class from OP.  nobody knows, what it actually does.